# Where is the Feature output for the Voronoi texture node?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

Does anyone know how to find the Feature Output for the Voronoi texture in the shader editor? It didn't show any at all.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Feature Output determines which points are used to calculate the distance.
It's the one with F1, F2... values.

Keep in mind that Voronoi Texture node have changed somewhat between 2.8 and 2.83.

[image] [image]